# How can i set state value after destructing in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I tried to destructure and set the value in state using React Hooks,but their it shows a syntax error.Since i am new on react JS,please help me for the solution.

Following below is my code:

I set the state as following:

```
const [Datasets, setDatasets] = useState({
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Total Cases',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,19,12,1)',
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: []
    },
    {
      label: 'Total Recovered',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: []
    },
    {
      label: 'Total Deaths',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: []
    }
  ]
})
```

I used useEffect to fetch data from API and set state.Following are my codes on useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://data.nepalcorona.info/api/v1/covid/timeline')
    .then(res => {
      setTimelinedata(res.data)
      setDatasets({ ...Datasets, labels: res.data.map((item) => item.date) })
      setDatasets([Datasets.datasets[0].data: res.data.map((item) => item.totalCases)])
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("error>>", err);
        })
    })
```

when i try to run the code the  error is shown in the following code:

```
setDatasets([Datasets.datasets[0].data: res.data.map((item) => item.totalCases)])
```

following error is shown:

[image]

following are the data i have fetched from the API:

[image]

Please help me for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please `useEffect` with below one. Moreover, you should use empty dependency array `[]` as an second parameter in `useEffect` to run api once. Moreover, you missed to put `})` before `catch`

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://data.nepalcorona.info/api/v1/covid/timeline')
            .then(res => {
                setTimelinedata(res.data);
                setDatasets({...Datasets, labels: res.data.map((item) => item.date)});
                let newDatasets = {...Datasets};
                newDatasets.datasets[0].data = res.data.map((item) => item.totalCases);
                newDatasets.datasets[1].data = res.data.map((item) => item.newRecoveries);
                newDatasets.datasets[2].data = res.data.map((item) => item.totalDeaths);
                setDatasets({...Datasets, ...newDatasets});

                console.log(Datasets, 'datasets');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("error>>", err);
            })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[Datasets.datasets[0].data: res.data.map((item) => item.totalCases)]` of of `setDatasets([Datasets.datasets[0].data: res.data.map((item) => item.totalCases)])` is an array, you can not have `:` in array like that.
Try this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://data.nepalcorona.info/api/v1/covid/timeline')
          .then(res => {
              setTimelinedata(res.data)
              const labels = res.data.map((item) => item.date)
              const data = res.data.map((item) => item.totalCases)
              setDatasets({ labels: res.data.map((item) => item.date, [{...Datasets.datasets[0], data: data}, ...Datasets.datasets])})
          .catch(err => {
              console.log("error>>", err);
          })
    })
```

Comment: how can i set state value of array inside array without using : ?what may be the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike class-based components' `setState`, the functional components' `useState` hook ***does not*** merge state updates into existing state, this needs to be done manually.

***NOTE:*** Don't forget to add a dependency array so the effect isn't triggered each render by the state update and cause an infinite loop. Empty array will trigger the effect when the component mounts, but you can add others if you need to update dataset later after component has been mounted, similar to `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function from class-based components.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://data.nepalcorona.info/api/v1/covid/timeline')
    .then(res => {
      setTimelinedata(res.data)
      setDatasets(Datasets => { // <-- Use a functional state update since next state could depend on previous state
        const labels = [
          ...Datasets.labels, // spread in existing labels
          ...res.data.map((item) => item.date) // spread in new labels
        ];

        const datasets = [
          ...Datasets.datasets, // spread in existing datasets
        ];

        // Now you can copy the total cases into the first index.
        datasets[0].data = res.data.map((item) => item.totalCases);

        return {
          ...Datasets, // spread in existing state
          labels,
          datasets,
        };
      });
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error>>", err);
    });
}, []); // <-- Empty dependency array to run once, on mount
```